# How to improve your web application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I want to do better, and I want to ear from you about what benefits does something and does it worst to add it to a web application.

I do a lot of ASP.NET applications, specially to run inside an CRM application.  Something like beeing completly in the user and we 'forget' about it until we receive an email :)

This question is for commercial an free web applications. And all the ideas below, **I will freely share my source code**.

Currently I just have some ideas and implemented others, like:

- if you add &debug=y to the query string I will show a debug window with all queries and procedures called

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/WebApp_DebugInfo.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/WebApp_DebugInfo.png)

- using global.asax I show a nicer error message to the user rather than the original ASP.NET error window (this is a developer version, the user version does not have the stack trace information)

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/WebApp_errorMsg.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/WebApp_errorMsg.png)

- I've created, using jQuery and a Web Service, a simple link that will show the current version of the web application and if is that the latest.
- Yesterday I read about [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) from [Scotts](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/posts/13845.aspx) blog and I will try to set this up in order to get an email to a special address, in order to improve and fix any bug that might happen...

What do you guys suggest? what can be considerate as a 'standard' on deploying web applications...

Comment: Here are some good links to guide you in improving your asp.net web application: [Improve performance 1](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/667/improve-perfomance-in-aspnet/) [Improve performance 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998549.aspx) [Improve performance 3](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33519)

Answer (score 1):

I like everything you are doing except for the displaying all query information via the querystring parameter.  I would suggest that feature only be available in debug mode on a dev. server or something of that nature. It could otherwise pose a large security risk.

I also see in that query you posted (line third from the bottom) ends in

```
where <some field> = 582
```

It would be a good idea to use parameterized queries instead of string concatenations.  It leaves you open for a slew of nasty problems like slower performance and sql-injection attacks.  If you use parameterized queries, that would go away.

Hope I added some value to your "standard".

Best of luck.

Comment: they are better than parametrized queries, they are using SuperOffice ORM :) that is only the output of the query for debugging information... when something is wrong and we want to see what is happening instead of call me to debug :) but I appreciate your input :)

Answer (score 0):

"If you add &debug=y to the query string I will show a debug window with all queries and procedures called"

Now, normally I'm the one to *criticize* security by obscurity, but this is a very bad  idea.  There's no reason to completely expose your implementation like this.  If you have this debug option enabled on a production server, at most you should log to an internal file.

Same goes with your "helpful" traceback error message.  This info is restricted for a reason.

Even the version link can be considered a vulnerability.  See e.g. [this Wordpress artice](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) which advices not publishing the Wordpress version you're using due to the multitude of past vulnerabilities and the fact that people are very slow to upgrade.